# how to display attribute group set on compare list page on frontend?

Tags: compare

I want to display Attribute Group set Name on frontend of compare page. i tired due to searching.
anybody knows how to make attribute group set on compare product page list. please help. your help be appreciated.

my code is

In `app/design/frontent/sm-market/default/template/catalog/product/compare/list.phtml`

```
<?php
<div class="page-title title-buttons">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Compare Products') ?></h1>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;" class="link-print"><?php echo $this->__('Print This Page') ?></a>
</div>
<?php $_total=$this->getItems()->getSize() ?>
<?php if($_total): ?>
    <table class="data-table compare-table" id="product_comparison">
    <?php $_i=0 ?>
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
            <col width="1" />
        <?php endif; ?>
            <col width="<?php echo floor(100/$_total); ?>%" />
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php if ($_total>2): ?>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <?php $_i=0 ?>
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td class="a-right"><a href="#" class="btn-remove" onclick="removeItem('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getRemoveUrl($_item) ?>');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
<?php endif ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="product-shop-row">
            <?php $_i=0 ?>
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td>
                    <a class="product-image" href="#" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>', true)" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(125, 125); ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>', true)" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, 'short') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-top') ?>
                    <?php if($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>', true)">                        
                        <span class="addcard-text"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                        </button></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <li>                                
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist button" onclick="setPLocation(this.href, true)"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $_attribute): ?>
            <tr>
                <?php $_i=0 ?>
                <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $_attribute->getStoreLabel() ?></span></th>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td>
                    <?php switch ($_attribute->getAttributeCode()) {
                        case "price": ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-' . $_attribute->getCode()) ?>
                            <?php break;
                        case "small_image": ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(125, 125); ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" />
                            <?php break;
                        case "date":
                              echo substr($this->getProductAttributeValue($_item, $_attribute),0,10);
                              break;
                        default: ?>
                            <div class="std">
                                <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $this->getProductAttributeValue($_item, $_attribute), $_attribute->getAttributeCode()) ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php break;
                    } ?>
                </td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
                <tr class="add-to-row">
                <?php $_i=0 ?>
                <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-bottom') ?>
                    <?php if($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>', true)">                        
                        <span class="addcard-text"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                        </button></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <li>                                
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item);?>" class="link-wishlist button" onclick="setPLocation(this.href, true)"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Close Window') ?>" class="button" onclick="window.close();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Close Window') ?></span></span></button>
        <span class="please-wait" id="compare-list-please-wait" style="display:none;">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Please wait...') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Please wait...') ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Please wait...') ?>
        </span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        decorateTable('product_comparison');

        function removeItem(url)
        {
            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                parameters: {isAjax: 1, method: 'POST'},
                onLoading: function(){$('compare-list-please-wait').show();},
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    $('compare-list-please-wait').hide();
                    window.location.reload();
                    window.opener.location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
<?php else: ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please help me.

![http://imgur.com/a/KlZVq](https://imgur.com/a/KlZVq)

go to this link and see the screen shot of what i have required. i want to display group like this.

Comment: this is for magento1 or magento2? You want to create new attribute set or display existing one?

Comment: this is for magento 1.9

Comment: want to display existing attribute in group set

Comment: please help me. i am new in magento

Answer (score 0):

For fetching an `Attribute Set Name` of particular product, you need to have a product object. Then use below code to get `Attribute Set Name` :

```
$attrSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
//Here $product is an object of product.
$attrSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
$attrSetName  = $attrSetModel->getAttributeSetName();

// OR you can use a single line of code below:
$attrSetName = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($product->getAttributeSetId())->getAttributeSetName();
```

**UPDATE** : Replace your phtml (`app/design/frontent/sm-market/default/template/catalog/product/compare/list.phtml`) with following code :

```
<?php
<div class="page-title title-buttons">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Compare Products') ?></h1>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;" class="link-print"><?php echo $this->__('Print This Page') ?></a>
</div>
<?php $_total=$this->getItems()->getSize() ?>
<?php if($_total): ?>
    <table class="data-table compare-table" id="product_comparison">
    <?php $_i=0 ?>
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
            <col width="1" />
        <?php endif; ?>
            <col width="<?php echo floor(100/$_total); ?>%" />
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php if ($_total>2): ?>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <?php $_i=0 ?>
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td class="a-right"><a href="#" class="btn-remove" onclick="removeItem('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getRemoveUrl($_item) ?>');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
<?php endif ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="product-shop-row">
            <?php $_i=0 ?>
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td>
                    <a class="product-image" href="#" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>', true)" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(125, 125); ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>', true)" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, 'short') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-top') ?>
                    <?php if($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>', true)">                        
                        <span class="addcard-text"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                        </button></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <li>                                
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist button" onclick="setPLocation(this.href, true)"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $_attribute): ?>
            <tr>
                <?php $_i=0 ?>
                <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $_attribute->getStoreLabel() ?></span></th>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td>
                    <?php switch ($_attribute->getAttributeCode()) {
                        case "price": ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-' . $_attribute->getCode()) ?>
                            <?php break;
                        case "small_image": ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(125, 125); ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" />
                            <?php break;
                        case "date":
                              echo substr($this->getProductAttributeValue($_item, $_attribute),0,10);
                              break;
                        default: ?>
                            <div class="std">
                                <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $this->getProductAttributeValue($_item, $_attribute), $_attribute->getAttributeCode()) ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php break;
                    } ?>
                </td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <!-- CHANGES ADDED -->
        <tr>
            <?php $attrSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set"); ?>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__("Attribute Group") ?></span></th>
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <td>
                    <div class="std">
                    <?php echo $attrSetName = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($_item->getAttributeSetId())->getAttributeSetName(); ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        <!-- CHANGES ENDED -->
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
                <tr class="add-to-row">
                <?php $_i=0 ?>
                <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-bottom') ?>
                    <?php if($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>', true)">                        
                        <span class="addcard-text"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                        </button></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <li>                                
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item);?>" class="link-wishlist button" onclick="setPLocation(this.href, true)"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Close Window') ?>" class="button" onclick="window.close();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Close Window') ?></span></span></button>
        <span class="please-wait" id="compare-list-please-wait" style="display:none;">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Please wait...') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Please wait...') ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Please wait...') ?>
        </span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        decorateTable('product_comparison');

        function removeItem(url)
        {
            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                parameters: {isAjax: 1, method: 'POST'},
                onLoading: function(){$('compare-list-please-wait').show();},
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    $('compare-list-please-wait').hide();
                    window.location.reload();
                    window.opener.location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
<?php else: ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sir , i just want to  display attribute groups for those product which are in compare list. i mean to say when we view compare product list the those product have to display attribute group set. I am using magento 1.9 . please suggest me. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have provided the same code. You can use it anywhere. Just need to pass product object, that's it

Comment: Please tell me details process of displaying attribute group set of compare list product

Comment: please help me. i am new in magento

Comment: sir i have edit my question and shown you compare controller so please  edit it.

Comment: controller has nothing to do here. Which theme are you using ?

Comment: i am using sm-market theme

Comment: where to put this code?

Comment: which template is used to show compare list ? Show this phtml here

Comment: Updated my answer. Does it works ?

Comment: i updated ur answer in my  file it showing attribute group set name but i want to display attribute group set like product detail page

Comment: i updated my question and send the link of screenshoot that what i have required. i mean to say that we can add many attribute group name under one attribute set so i want to display this attribute group name separately on after view compare list. which are mentioned in screenshoot.

Comment: please understand my requirement and help me